# Analysis of "Wendell is here today"; in particular the phrase "here today"

Tags: grammar

When I started to analyze this sentence: *Wendell is here today.* I saw that a linking verb is used and immediately I thought that the phrase which follows must be a subject complement. But while analyzing it I realized that I might be mistaken since after the verb an adverbial phrase is used: *here today*. So I got confused is it now a subject complement or an adverbial adjunct?
Is in this case the verb *is* a linking verb?

Comment: We live in space-time.   He is here (location) today (time).  I was there yesterday. Advice: question the statement of the grammatical rules, not simple common sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wendell is here today.

What adverbial phrase?

We have "here", which you might regard as an intransitive preposition or an unusual adjective.   In phrases like "the weather here" and "this man here", it directly modifies a noun.   We have "today", which you might regard as a fused prepositional phrase or as a noun in its own right.

On thing we don't have is the phrase "here today".   Although that can exist as a phrase (it's hard to parse "here today, gone tomorrow" without regarding "here today" in that way) there's nothing to support that idea in this sentence.   We can separate those words completely without any change to the sentiment of the clause:

> Today Wendell is here.

That leaves us with "Wendell" as a subject, "is" as the copula, "here" as the subject complement, and "today" as an adjunct.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. But I'm really confused on why *here* would be a subject complement. Because subject complements can be nouns, adjectives or pronoun but it cannot be an adverb. This is my biggest dilemma. And I'm sorry about that phrase I saw two adverbs together and mistook it as a phrase.

Comment: Ok.  If we're talking about "some mistake here", we're not talking about an adverb, are we?  We have the noun "mistake", we have the adjective "some", and we do have the word "here".  One way or another, "here" also modifies "mistake".  So, whatever it is, do you see any reason to call it an adverb?

Comment: I really don't understand where you're going with this. And yes the word *here* is an adverb. And it is modifying the noun *mistake*.

Comment: I'm going somewhere very simple.  Adverbs don't modify nouns.

Comment: Yes but there are said to be cases that an adverb can actually modify a noun. In this phrase that you mentioned *here* is an adverb and if we compare it with this example:*Look at *the people there*, they are laughing.* *there* is an adverb modifying the noun *people*. Therefore if we analyze your phrase *here* is not modifying a verb, nor an adjective, nor an adverb. It is indeed modifying a noun, in my opinion.

Comment: There are a number of possibilities.  We could reasonably claim that words like "here" and "there" have homonyms.  Just like there's the noun "help" and the verb "help", there could be the adjective "here" and the adverb "here".  Or, we could reasonably claim that words like "here" and "there" are intransitive prepositions.  The preposition "here" can modify either a noun or a verb just like the prepositional phrase "in this place" can.  We *cannot* reasonably claim that "here" is always an adverb.  We *cannot* reasonably claim that adverbs modify nouns.

Comment: However I'm still not understanding why you choose to analyze the phrase *some mistake here* since I don't think is related to the question I asked earlier.